# JAX-RS (Jersey) creates related object instead of null

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

problem is rather simple, but kinda hard to explain.

I have REST service like this:

```
@Path("categories")
@RequestScoped
public class CategoryResource {

    @Inject
    CategoriesFacade dao;

    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void putJson(Categories content) {
        System.err.println(content.toString()); // <-- ?????
        dao.edit(content);
    }

    // ....
}
```

And entity object like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Categories implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 5)
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private Categories parentId;

    // ....    

}
```

Here is http request payload:

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/categories
Data: {"categoryId":"7162","name":"test","parentId":null}
```

And here is Categories object i get in `@PUT` request (see line marked with ????):

```
Categories{
  categoryId=7162,
  name=test,
  parentId=Categories{categoryId=null, name=null, parentId=null}
}
```

So as you can see here, `parentId` is assigned with empty `Categories` object, this way
i'm getting ValidationException, because `name` could not be null.

Any idea how to make Jersey to give me this kind of  object, so null value for parentId will be fine:

```
Categories{
  categoryId=7162,
  name=test,
  parentId=null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stringify your object on client site (for example, if client on JavaScropt, using method `JSON.stringify`).
Rest method make

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
public void putJson(String content) {
```

And convert json string to object (for eample, using google json)

```
Categories cont = new com.google.gson.Gson().fromJson(content, Categories.class);
```